# defining rename command scope; replace word; replace entire file name; wildcards

Tags: filenames, rename, wildcards, replace

Im looking to use the `rename` command to edit file names. More specifically, Im trying to isolate specific pieces to change, or in some cases, the whole name.

### For example:

Lets say I have three directories… (test-file-1, example2, third)

If I wanted to change "test-file-1" to "file 1"
*I know I could use* `rename 's/test-file-1/file 1/' *`

How could I set a wild card so I dont have to give the explicit file name to be changed?

> I've tried `rename 's/tes*/file 1/' *` *to no avail*

Similarly, I would like to know if it's possible to change the whole file name using wildcards.

> I've tried `rename 's/^*/file 1/' test*`

Im not entirely sure if I can use the second asterisk to match the files to be processed or not but the same question applies to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using regular expressions correctly. `tes*` means `te` with any number of `s`s following it, so `test-file-1` will be renamed to `file 1t-file-1`:

```
$ rename -n 's/tes*/file 1/' *
test-file-1 renamed as file 1t-file-1
```

Similarly, `^*` will match the empty string appearing at the start, so in effect it's like `^`, but with a an inifinite loop:

```
$ rename -n 's/^*/file 1/' *  
^* matches null string many times in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^* <-- HERE / at (eval 1) line 1.
example2 renamed as file 1example2
^* matches null string many times in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^* <-- HERE / at (eval 2) line 1.
test-file-1 renamed as file 1test-file-1
^* matches null string many times in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^* <-- HERE / at (eval 3) line 1.
third renamed as file 1third
```

You should, instead, use `.*` - `.` matches all characters except the newline, usually:

```
$ rename -n 's/tes.*/file 1/' *
test-file-1 renamed as file 1

$ rename -n 's/.*/file 1/' *      
example2 renamed as file 1
test-file-1 renamed as file 1
third renamed as file 1
```

Naturally I'd expect this last command to create problems.